# Website jumping down on page load with embedded iframe google form

Tags: html

When someone navigates to a particular page with a google web form on it, the browser automatically jumps down to the google web form near the bottom of the page.

[Website URL](http://liff2013.com/sugarman)

Any ideas on how to keep it at the top of the page?

Thanks!
Jeff

Answer (score 2):

Its due to the a field in the form getting focus, if you can stop that it wont jump down.

I've had a look at google forms and it doesn't look like there is a way to configure it not to set focus, you could try some custom javascript to stop it.

Comment: Yea, I thought this may have been the problem. I did some googling, but couldn't find a way to stop the google form from getting focus. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe specifying focus on something higher up the page? Although the js that does that would have to fire after the google form has loaded probably meaning your page will jump down then back up again. The only other thing i can think of is not loading the form until somebody either scrolls down to it or clicks on something.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the URL shared that the original user's issue is now resolved, but fyi for others seeking a solution, if the Google Form is embedded via an iFrame, or you're using a custom HTML form to post answers to a Google form via the `target` of an iFrame, and this jumping occurs, changing the `src=''` of the iFrame to `src='about:blank'` worked a treat to eliminate any jumping of the page.